# Jupyter "escapes" virtualenv via .local files. How do I mitigate this?

Tags: python, containers, virtualenv, jupyter, rc

I've noticed on multiple occasions that Jupyter has a tendency to "escape" from a virtualenv environment and cause conflict issues in different projects. After tracking one bug involving javascript widgets, which worked in a fresh user space, but not in a fresh virtualenv, I found that the problem resided in a file in `~/.local/share/jupyter`. Not sure how it got there, but removing this resolved the problem. I imagine `~/.jupyter` may cause cross-env side effects as well.

How can I create a virtualenv such that each env has its own `.local`/`.jupyter` or whatever other `.foobarspam` config files, such that I don't get side effects between projects, without resorting to something like Docker?